# Showing value inisde validation message with yup and formik

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am trying to use yup with formik and i18n.
The issue is how can I show error message with the value itself 
My code is

```
   retention: Yup.number()
      .test(
        t("Validation {{current}}{{min}}{{max}}", { current: Yup.ref('retention'), min: 12, max: 91 }),
        function (value) {
          return (value > 12 && value <= 91)
        }
      ),
```

I cant see the error message currectly U think the problem with getting the Yup.ref

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final I find the answer

```
  Size: Yup.number()
            .test(
            (Size) =>
                t("Size Validation {{current}}{{min}}{{max}}", { current: Size.value, min: 1, max: 90 }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Yup.number()
  .when('retention', (retentionValue, schema) => {
    // you can use the value of retention and modify the schema if you want to.
    return schema;
  })
```

For more info visit the official [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).

Comment: I am trying to do something like this  retentionPeriod: Yup.number()
      .test("Retention Validation Range",
        (value = Yup.ref('retentionPeriod')) =>
          value,   but it isnt working